# How do I check if an array is sorted with SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE arr(
id int,
arr_r int []
);
INSERT INTO arr(arr_r ) VALUES
( ARRAY [1 ,2 ,3]) ,
( ARRAY [4 ,3]) ,
( ARRAY [7 ,6]) ,
( ARRAY [2 ,2]);
```

and I want to output the arrays in the table which are sorted in ascending order. An output would be

```
1, 2, 3
2, 2
```

I tried some stuff with array_agg and an order by inside the array_agg but that did not work. How would I go about getting the desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [install](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createextension.html) the [intarray extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/intarray.html), then you can do:

```
select *
from arr
where arr_r = sort(arr_r);
```

If you don't want to install the extension, you can create your own sort function:

```
create function sort(p_input int[]) 
  returns int[]
as
$$
  select array_agg(i order by i)
  from unnest(p_input) as a(i);
$$
language sql
immutable;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=199fa91f9bcc6a59061ca5a287fe38f7)

Comment: Wow thanks! The only problem I have left is that it gives me multiple rows of the same results. Using distinct didnt do the job here.

Comment: @NuTa: well, then you have duplicates in your initial table, which will obviously be returned by this query.

Comment: @NuTa: do you want to remove duplicate entries from the array?

Comment: oh, you were right. I didnt drop the table when I ran my script so it created multiple lines and therefore showed many lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can eliminate duplicates by selecting unique values from unnest

```
create or replace 
function sort_int_array(p_input int[]) 
 returns int[]
as
$$
  select array_agg(i order by i)
    from ( select distinct unnest(p_input) i) a;
$$
language sql
immutable;

--- Test
select sort_int_array(array[1,3,2,5,7,5,3,6,8,8,9,0])
```

Comment: you can also use `array_agg(distinct i ...)`

Comment: True, I forgot about the distinct option in array_agg; which is better. Oh well, guess we all have there moments especially when switching between databases.